# Find the antiderivative $x=(2/y)$

Tags: integration

What is the antiderivative of $x=\frac{2}{y}$?

I have to find the antiderivative to do a volume problem, revolving around the y-axis.

I tried doing it, and I think it's $\frac{4y^3}{3}\pi $

Comment: The given function can be written as $2y^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Given the rule that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=\frac1x \Rightarrow\int\frac1x\;\mathrm{dx} = \ln x + C$$

I would say that if you were integrating with respect to y,

$$\int\frac2y\;\mathrm{dy} = 2\ln y + C$$

If you wanted with respect to x, we need to rearrange the equation to make y the subject.
$$x = \frac 2y $$
$$y = \frac2x $$
Thus, similar to the 1st case, $$\int\frac2x\;\mathrm{dx} = 2\ln x + C$$

Side note: in all cases except power of negative one we would use the reverse power rule as follows: 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (x^n)=nx^{n-1} \Rightarrow\int x^n\;\mathrm{dx} =\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$
For you to obtain $\frac{4y^3}{3} (+ C)$ you would be integrating $4y^2$ with respect to y. Thus I suspect some info is missing or the formula you gave might be wrong.

Comment: @mattos oops, sorry for the typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, this depends on what variable it is being integrated with respect to.

Also, I'm not sure how you got pi in your answer. Once you've calculated the volume it would be appropriate, but just on the basis of the function x = (2/y) I don't understand why integration would yield pi.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the pi from the volume. So with pi it would be (4y^3)/(3)?

Comment: Well, it depends on what sort of volume you're working with. If it's a cylinder or sphere, then perhaps yes. Once again it depends on what the variable you are integrating with respect to is. If the integral is for y = (x/2)dx, then the integral is simply x^2/4, but if it is ydy = x/2, then the answer is 2ln|y|. However, with a volume integral, you may be working with a double or triple integral. Are you sure you're not omitting any info?

Comment: None, I did forget to mention that it's revolved around the y-axis, tho.